# Python: Find count of elements of one list when condition in another list is fulfilled

Tags: python, list, if-statement, count, range

Let's say I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = [3, 26, 17, 7, 35, 8, 14, 24]

list2 = [long, long, long, short, short, short, short, short]
```

I want to find the count of locations such that the element in `list1` is `> 10` and the corresponding element in `list2` is `short`.

My expected output is **3**, as the three items in indices 4, 6 and 7 (`35, 14, 24`) in `list1` are `> 10` and they correspond to `short`s in `list2`.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this and tell us what problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat these two lists as a list of pairs, you can `zip` them together, with something like the following.

Note that I'm using the `sum` function here to count the number of times the expression evaluates to `True` (with `True` automatically treated as `1` and `False` as `0`).

```
# Assuming that `long` and `short` are arbitrary objects
long = object()
short = object()

list1 = [3, 26, 17, 7, 35, 8, 14, 24]
list2 = [long, long, long, short, short, short, short, short]

print(sum(num > 10 and category is short
          for num, category in zip(list1, list2)))
```

Comment: Assuming the arbitrary objects are not singletons you should use `==` and not `is` to compare imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to iterate over both lists at the same time and increment a counter if a condition is met:

```py
count=0
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if x>10 and y=="short":
        count+=1
```

Keep in mind it will iterate until it reaches the end of the shorter iterable.

Answer (score 0):

When used in an arithmetic context, True and False have effective values of 1 and 0 respectively. Therefore:

```
list1 = [ 3, 26, 17, 7, 35, 8, 14, 24 ]
list2 = ['long','long','long','short','short','short','short','short']

print(sum(x > 10 and y == 'short' for x, y in zip(list1, list2)))
```

**Output:**

```
3
```